# Flutter Tooltip on One Tap

Tags: flutter, dart, tooltip

I want to show a tooltip on a **single tap**, not a **long tap**.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
Tooltip(
  message: e.title,
  child: Card(
    semanticContainer: true,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 12,
          horizontal: 12
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Image.network(
          e.icon,
          height: 40,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Current best answer is @pragmateek 's. That is the official solution, as the current Tooltip provides a way of doing what you need out-of-the-box. There is no need to wrap it up in any other Widget or make your own Tooltip.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to use `triggerMode` property inside Tooltip constructor.

```
  Tooltip(
    message: item.description ?? '',
    triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
    child: Text(item.label ?? '',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontSize: 1.7.t.toDouble(),
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
        )),
  )
```

Comment: Ideally this should work. But it doesn't in Flutter 2.14.2. Possible bug?

Comment: Also not working on my end. Flutter 2.10.3

Comment: This is not working on Flutter 3

Comment: this is working with flutter 3

Comment: Depends on your platform:
> This property does not affect mouse devices. Setting [triggerMode] to [TooltipTriggerMode.manual] will not prevent the tooltip from showing when the mouse cursor hovers over it.
from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip/triggerMode.html

Answer (score 39):

UPDATE:
use `triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,` instead

THIS SOLUTION IS OBSOLETE
as an option you can create simple wrapper widget
full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Home")),
      body: Center(
        child: MyTooltip(
          message: 'message',
          child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300', height: 40),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyTooltip extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final String message;

  MyTooltip({@required this.message, @required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = GlobalKey<State<Tooltip>>();
    return Tooltip(
      key: key,
      message: message,
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () => _onTap(key),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTap(GlobalKey key) {
    final dynamic tooltip = key.currentState;
    tooltip?.ensureTooltipVisible();
  }
}
```

Comment: I added a Timer after showing o Tooltip to hide it programmatically.

 Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 2500), () => tooltip?.dispose());

Comment: ^ Using `.dispose()` won't let the user reopen the tooltip. Instead try:  ```.deactivate()```

Comment: This is not the actual solution anymore. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69461966/5535773

Answer (score 0):

```
final tooltipController = JustTheController();

JustTheTooltip(
            controller: tooltipController,
            triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.manual,
            preferredDirection: AxisDirection.up,
            content: const SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(
                  'This is tooltip text',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                  tooltipController.showTooltip();
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.stars,
                  size: 22,
                  color: AppColors.orange,
                ),
            ),
          ),
```

this method is worked for me