# Flutter - Quick info UI

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjBSt.jpg). (The info button onTap must display that above popup)
I've searched everywhere and I could find anything ready to implement. I tried to do it manually myself but couldn't help.

Would be grateful if this community could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a widget for that scenario called **"Tooltip"** and some of the Material widgets come with tooltip included.

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.info),
  tooltip: "Your description here",
)
```

To find out more, you can check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeEfD5fI-5Q)

Check out this thread: [Flutter Tooltip on One Tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66153792/flutter-tooltip-on-one-tap)

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/super_tooltip

Got this package. Thanks man!